# Time Span Logic Error

Tags: c#

I have an error in my logic and am having trouble figuring out what it is.  Basically, I continuously calculate the time span of each iteration of the gaming loop and add that duration to the duration before it.  I am trying to calculate the total time the game is played. Of course, it doesn't produce the right results.  What am I doing wrong? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
        private TimeSpan totalDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        private int score = 0;

        public void Stop()
        {
            IsGameOver = true;
            //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Game Over\n\nScore = {0}", score));
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Game Over\n\nScore = {0}\n\nTime
            Duration={1}", score, totalDuration));
            Application.Exit();
        }

        public void Start()
        {

            score = 0;
            IsGameOver = false;

            currentRedLightX = 0;
            currentRedLightY = 0;

            currentGreenLightX = width / 2;
            currentGreenLightY = height / 2;


            double minIterationDuration = SPEED; // 50 frames / sec

            //game loop
            while (!IsGameOver)
        {
            if (IsCollision())
            {
                score += 10;
            }

            DateTime startIterationTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
            UpdateGameState();
            Render();
            DateTime endIterationTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeSpan iterationDuration = endIterationTime - startIterationTime;
            totalDuration += iterationDuration;
            //totalDuration += iterationDuration.Duration();                
            if (iterationDuration.TotalMilliseconds < minIterationDuration)
                Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(minIterationDuration - 
                iterationDuration.TotalMilliseconds));

            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including in your timing anything that happens in your `DoEvents` call - so you're not going to capture all of the time the game's running.

If all you're doing is displaying the total duration, why not just use the start and end time of the game for that, instead of summing all of the tiny intervals inbetween?

Comment: Okay, so I figured it out.  StopWatch is not supported on my .NET compact platform.  So I used the regular DateTime and TimeSpan instead. I had to start the time as soon as my start() method was called and stop the time when my stop() method was called.  Then all I had to do was get the duration and display it.  Dooh!  Seems so simple now. Why couldn't I think of it before?  At least I know now. Thanks Dan and everyone else!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of timespan, use the [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to calculate elapsed time:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
// Do stuff ...
stopWatch.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.UtcNow` will have a relatively low accuracy. Assuming your loop is fairly fast, I wouldn't be at all surprised to find out that most of the time, `iterationDuration` is actually zero - leading to the incorrect results. That's why using a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) (use the same one repeatedly, calling `Start`/`Stop` appropriately but not `Reset`) is a better approach. `Stopwatch` will use a high-resolution system timer if one is available.

As an aside, sleeping in the UI thread and using `Application.DoEvents` is pretty nasty in terms of UI programming. I wonder if you *really* want a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead...

Answer (score 1):

I guess the thing you are missing in your logic is to take into account the time you are sending the thread to sleep. You might want to add that time either before or after sending it to sleep.

Comment: I saw Oded's answer, even if you use StopWatch class, if you start and stop it and not include the time the thread is asleep, it wont count the total time the game is played if not used at the right time in your loop.